# How to understand the type like `T (*(T, std::_Placeholder<2>))(T, T)`?

Tags: c++, c++11

A simple code snippet

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>

int main() {
    auto f = std::bind(printf, "%d", std::placeholders::_2);
}
```

transforms to

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
  std::_Bind<int (*(const char *, std::_Placeholder<2>))(const char *, ...)> f = std::bind(printf, "%d", std::placeholders::_2);
  return 0;
}
```

using cppinsights.io. (See https://cppinsights.io/s/71938cf6)

How to understand the `int (*(const char *, std::_Placeholder<2>))(const char *, ...)` part of return type `std::_Bind<int (*(const char *, std::_Placeholder<2>))(const char *, ...)>`?

I know that `int (*)(const char *, ...)` is a function pointer type, but what's the meaning of `(*(const char *, std::_Placeholder<2>))`? Is there any link to further understand this type?

Edited: My bad for a misleading title. What I want to ask, is how to understand the type `int (*(const char *, std::_Placeholder<2>))(const char *, ...)`, and how to name this type. `std::bind` is just an introduction to this question, and it gives me a strange type that I have never seen before.

Comment: Looks like a function returning a pointer to a function to me, but I could easily be wrong.

Comment: The return type of `std::bind()` is unspecified and implementation-defined. You don't need to understand its type, only its behavior. It refers to the bound callable, and it will invoke that callable when itself is invoked via its call `operator()`. Period.

Comment: @RemyLebeau -- it's not implementation defined (which requires that the implementation document its behavior). It's simply unspecified.

Comment: Re: "transforms to ..." -- with that particular compiler and standard library implementation. There is no requirement on the particular types involved. The return type is unspecified; the only requirement is that it can be called with appropriate argument type(s). The name `_Bind` begins with an underscore followed by a capital letter; it's reserved for use by the implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's really no need to understand the type that `std::bind` returns.

With that said, one can't really separate the different parts of the template type here in the way that is done in the question, they are all parts of a *single* type and can only use used as a whole. It basically boils down to a function that returns a pointer to another function, and that other function (`printf` actually) returns an `int`.

It might be easier if we use type-aliases:

```
using printf_function_type = int(const char *, ...);

using wrapped_function_type = printf_function_type*(const char *, std::_Placeholder<2>);

using bind_type = std::_Bind<wrapped_function_type>;
```

The first alias is for the `printf` function.

The second alias is a function that takes a `const char *` and a "placeholder" object as arguments, and returns a pointer to the `printf`-type function.

The third alias is the internal compiler-specific type for the callable object using the function.

What your `std::bind` call return is a value of type `bind_type`.

Answer (score 1):

Not to say that I found this without knowing the solution.
But I recently discovered this way to express some function (and function pointer) types:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>

int main() {
  
std::_Bind<int (*(const char *, std::_Placeholder<2>))(const char *, ...)> f = std::bind(printf, "%d", std::placeholders::_2);  return 0;

using T = std::_Bind< int (*(const char *, std::_Placeholder<2>))(const char *, ...)               >;

using U = std::_Bind< auto(const char *, std::_Placeholder<2>) ->  auto(*)(const char *, ...)->int >;

static_assert( std::is_same<T, U>::value );
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qbjfMEMf7

Reading from left to right, "it is a function with `char*` and `Placeholder` input that outputs a function *pointer* with `char*` (and variadic) input and integer output".

Note that parenthesis cannot be used for type declarations (like in expressions), so I used extra spaces to make the associativity clear.

(Using east-const in addition can also help.)